# Get the maximum value and the key of the corresponding array from an array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am really sorry about this confusing question, but essentially I have a PHP array made up of multiple other arrays. Of these arrays, I'd like to extract the array with the maximum value in the cpmbid column of the relevant array.

```php
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cid] => 1 [accountid] => anaccount [orderid] => two [campaigntype] => CPM [bid] => 1.40000 [creativename] => Creative 2 [imgsource] => https://i1.wp.com/test-bucket-dfn.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/24122252/NATPE-300x250.jpg?ssl=1 [clickthrough] => https://google.com/search?q=ad3 [targethostname] => localhost [targetpath] => all [keyvalue1] => my [keyvalue2] => any [keyvalue3] => any [width] => 300 [height] => 250 [dayrem] => 4 [clickrem] => 0 [imprem] => 1019 ) [1] => Array ( [cid] => 2 [accountid] => anaccount [orderid] => one [campaigntype] => CPM [bid] => 1.60000 [creativename] => Creative 2 [imgsource] => https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSm2kj7NQ0uuIxYqSA4-3dd1-I_x2xcpq2LmMfAcUOTG2AVv2n6bCkONgr1uVNJJO8EFIg&usqp=CAU [clickthrough] => https://google.com/search?q=ad2 [targethostname] => localhost [targetpath] => /home/no [keyvalue1] => hello [keyvalue2] => my [keyvalue3] => friend [width] => 300 [height] => 250 [dayrem] => 2 [clickrem] => 0 [imprem] => 753 ) [2] => Array ( [cid] => 3 [accountid] => anaccount [orderid] => three [campaigntype] => CPM [bid] => 2.30000 [creativename] => Creative 3 [imgsource] => https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmZIh09uRp3ADOszQz6APBuCOmd6H_cQ-Dew&usqp=CAU [clickthrough] => https://google.com/search?q=ad4 [targethostname] => localhost [targetpath] => /fruitsalad/page.html [keyvalue1] => any [keyvalue2] => any [keyvalue3] => any [width] => 300 [height] => 250 [dayrem] => 2 [clickrem] => 0 [imprem] => 1000 ) [3] => Array ( [cid] => 4 [accountid] => anaccount [orderid] => two [campaigntype] => CPM [bid] => 1.90000 [creativename] => Creative 4 [imgsource] => https://i1.wp.com/test-bucket-dfn.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/24122252/NATPE-300x250.jpg?ssl=1 [clickthrough] => https://google.com/search?q=ad5 [targethostname] => localhost [targetpath] => all [keyvalue1] => any [keyvalue2] => any [keyvalue3] => any [width] => 300 [height] => 250 [dayrem] => 4 [clickrem] => 0 [imprem] => 4013 ) )
//This is the Array, I want to select the array in which the highest 'bid' value is, any answers?
```

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question, and I appreciate any answers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with following code, it will find max value then max array based on value:

```
$maxval=max(array_column($array,"bid")); 
$maxarray=array_keys(array_column($array,"bid"),$maxval);
print_R($array[$maxarray[0]]);
```

$array = your array,

Comment: @Timothy I have updated code so if you have duplicate in highest value then you will get all keys in $maxarray.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column to get an array of values for specific key, and max it.

```
max(array_column($array, 'bid'))
```

Comment: I know, but if I use array_search() to find the relevant key, I risk fetching the wrong key with the same bid, is there a way to avoid this?